# How to install drivers for brother printer

Tags: installation, drivers, printing, deb

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS. My Brother DCP-130C usb printer is correctly detected but the drivers for a DCP-1200 are installed by default. I have downloaded what I assume are the correct drivers from Brother (deb format) but don't know what to do now. The .deb file is in my downloads folder. I am a newbie to Linux/Ubuntu so climbing a bit of a learning curve. Hope someone can help
Roy

Comment: doubleclick the .deb and watch the system do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install your .deb file:

- Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and Go to downloads where you file is located:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- Then execute this command to intall it:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i *yourprinterfilename.deb*
  ```
- That's it.. Replace *yourprinterfilename.deb* with your actual printer's file name.

Reply for further assistance..